# Why is movement speed changing in my code but not jumpspeed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Weird, I made this simple running code, and the speed addition works just fine, but for some reason the jumpspeed doesn't change...

Of course this isn't the full code this is just the important part, any idea why ?

```
//Run
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
{ 
    speed = 30.0f;
    jumpSpeed = 60.0F;
} 
else
{
    speed = 20.0f;
    jumpSpeed = 30.0F;
}
```

I can post more of the code if needed

Comment: This code can't be wrong. What can be wrong is how you use `jumpSpeed` itself

Comment: Please do show the whole script...

Answer (score 0):

There must be something else because I have tested your code and it worked correctly.

Have you correctly added the `jumpSpeed` to your object ?

Comment: what do you mean have i correctly added the jump speed to my object ?

Comment: I mean, that part of the code is correct, but we need to see where your jumpSpeed variable is used to understand why it is not applied.